# Ruby no longer loading BigDecimal by default

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shared-libraries

After months without issue, I've begun to get an error saying that BigDecimal isn't loaded (specifically `uninitialized constant BigDecimal`). The simple solution would of course be to just add the require statement as needed, but I'm working on this project with several others and this issue is only affecting me. It's happening on both of my computers (MacOS + Arch), and I'm generally curious as to why this would suddenly start.

I had a suspicion that it could be something to do with switching from system Ruby to RVM-managed Ruby, but switching back to system Ruby didn't remedy the issue. I've done some searching on this and haven't come up with anything.

Comment: Just tested in every ruby I have installed, going back to 1.9.3 and I have to require BigDecimal in all of them, and don't actually remember being able to use that library without requiring it. Is there some project config file the others have that you're missing that requires it?

Comment: My question is, what facility in Ruby could cause something to be imported for some but not all of the people using this code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use require bigdecimel to use it, Probably some of the dependency gems for your app were requiring it before so that you didn't had to require them manually